# Angular 2 query builder json object convert to SQL Server where query

Tags: sql, angular, query-builder

How can we convert an Angular 2 query builder in the below-linked json object to a SQL Server `where` condition?

https://embed.plnkr.co/13rGVC/

Comment: please explain your problem

Comment: Please try to make at least some effort when posting a question.